# Combine xsd which import another xsd as a single xsd file

Tags: java, python, scala, xsd

I have a master xsd file say  “Master.xsd” which import another xsd “LinckerXSD1” inside it . 
I want to copy  schema of LinckerXSD1 to  Master so that it result  another xsd file .
This need to be done recursively means   Master.xsd may have more than one import statement’s &  LinckerXSD1 may import another xsd inside it !!!

```
Master.xsd :- 
<xs:import namespace="file:////home/i88691/work-Area/xsdLinker/LinckerXSD1.xsd" schemaLocation="LinckerXSD1.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="school">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Addresses" minOccurs="0" nillable="true">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Entry" type="Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" xmlns="file:////home/i88691/work-Area/xsdLinker/LinckerXSD1.xsd"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

LinckerXSD1 :- 

<xs:element name="Entry">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="hosename" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="hoseplase" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

Required Output :-
<xs:import namespace="file:////home/i88691/work-Area/xsdLinker/LinckerXSD1.xsd" schemaLocation="LinckerXSD1.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="school">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Entry">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="hosename" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="hoseplase" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hand (as you seem to have been doing) or a number of tools exist that will do this for you, have a look at [Liquid Studio](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/trial-download) - [Flatten Schema](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/reference/xmlstudio/webframe.html?XSD_Editor_FlattenSchema.html). This will not expand the definitions in-place, but it will put everything into a single file.

**Note:** Collapsing a number of XSD's into a single one is only possible if all the XSD's share the same targetnamespace.